# Realign divs vertically when switching to a small (e.g. mobile) screen

Tags: html, css

My question is quite straight forward. I'm using div to create a table.

```
        <div class="table">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

    </div>
```

Used with the following css :

```
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: thick; }
.cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 10px 0 10px;}
```

Now I would like to have the "cells" all stacked on top of each other when I use a small (mobile for example) device.

Could you give me a hand with twinning my @media css for that ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Use `.cell{display:block}` in your @media for mobile:

```css
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: thick; }
.cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0 10px 0 10px; }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.cell{
  display:block
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="table">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">a</div>
            <div class="cell"><img src="..."></div>
            <div class="cell">b</div>
            <div class="cell">c</div>
            <div class="cell">d</div>
            <div class="cell">e</div>            
        </div>

    </div>
```